# ProjectItems.AddFromDirectory does not working with VS2015

Tags: c#

I need to copy a directory programmatically to my project. I have used the code below in my project:

```
ProjectItems.AddFromDirectory(_projectPath + "\\Folder");
```

But it does not copy the whole directory. it just added the root folder to the project. Am facing this with VS2015 alone.

any solution to this?

Comment: try ProjectItems.AddFromDirectory(_projectPath + "\Folder"); and please check if you have write permissions

Comment: Hi probably that wont work,  single slash can not be recognized inside ""  .so that we have used "\\".

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: Hi that is the default behavior of VS15. so AddFromDirectory will add root folder alone

Comment: Also having this issue and haven't seen any answer suggested yet.

Comment: Please check ouy my answer. I think it is what you might be looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the most elegant solution possible.
But it is using AddFromDirectory as requested.
I tested this using Visual Studio 2015 Professional.

```
public static void RefreshItemsInProject(Project project, string projectPath)
{
  foreach(string subDirectoryPath in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(projectPath))
    AddItemsToProjectFromDirectory(project.ProjectItems, subDirectoryPath));
}

private static readonly HashSet<string> _excluded = new HashSet<string>() { "bin", "obj" };

public static void AddItemsToProjectFromDirectory(ProjectItems projectItems, string directoryPath)
{
  //very weird GetDirectoryName returns the FULL PATH!!!! 
  //When using GetFileName on a Directory it actually returns the FolderName WITHOUT the PATH.
  var directoryName = Path.GetFileName(directoryPath);

  if(_excluded.Contains(directoryName.ToLower()))//folder to exclude like bin and obj.
    return;//return right away if the folder has been excluded.

  var subFolder = projectItems.AddFromDirectory(directoryPath);

  foreach(string subDirectoryPath in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(directoryPath))
    AddItemsToProjectFromDirectory(subFolder.ProjectItems, subDirectoryPath);
}
```

To use this code call like this:

```
RefreshItemsInProject(myProject, projectPath);
```

myProject is of type EnvDTE.Project

You can call this on a project everytime something changes; like a new file was added for example; and it will refresh the contents of the project.

Notice it supports a list of "excluded" Directories to avoid including things like bin and obj in your project.

I hope this helps some one.

**UPDATE:** I realized this only works for SECOND LEVEL directories.
Like this:

**MyDir--->MySecondDir--->MyItems THIS WORKS!** Items in second level.

**MyDir--->MyItems THIS DOES NOT WORK!** Items in first level.

For some reason it fails to add the items in the first level directory.
Seems like a bug in Microsofts implementation. If some one could shed some light into the issue; I would really appreaciate it.